# A bound using Cauchy formula

Tags: integration

Let $0<t_0<1$  fixed number , $ n_0$ integer $ \geq 2$ fixed  and let  $\forall 0<u<1, f(u)= \displaystyle \frac{(1-u)^{n_0} \log(1-u)}{(1-ut_0)^{n_0+1}} $.

Let $0<u_0<1 $ be given.  I'm looking a good upper bound (which is an explicit  function in $u_0,t_0, n_0$) to $ |f^{(n_0)}(u_0)|$ ($n_0$-th derivative).

I suppose that by Cauchy formula, and choosing the good radius one can have a good upper bound, but I don't know how to do it. Any help?

Comment: $$|f^{(n_0)}(u_0)|=(1-{u_0})^{{n_0}-1} (1-{t_0} {u_0})^{-{n_0}-2}$$ $$\left| \left(\log ^2(1-{u_0}) ({n_0} ({t_0}-1)-{t_0} {u_0}+{t_0})+\log (1-{u_0}) (({n_0} (-{t_0})+{n_0}+{t_0} ({u_0}-1)) \log (1-{t_0} {u_0})+{t_0} {u_0}+{t_0}-2)+(1-{t_0} {u_0}) \log (1-{t_0} {u_0})\right)\right|$$ --- not just an upper bound, but an exact evaluation as an explicit function of $u_0$, $t_0$, $n_0$ (this seems to satisfy what you are asking, correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: i'll check this formula, thanks for your help